# Custom Validation of Array Value in Quform Wordpress Plugin

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, validation, plugins

I bought Quform wordpress plugin from codecanyon. The plugins is great - it allows you create custom validator for your forms as shown here http://support.themecatcher.net/quform-wordpress/guides/customization/creating-a-custom-validator.

The example above however only deals with one validating against a single value. What if I have 500 of them?

This is code that I have.

```
function custom_validator($valid, $value, $element, $rcnumber)
{
    $rcnumber = array('103184','104351','104359','103912','104389','104400','100505','102180','103530','104455','79162','74233','26451','75140','289752','101785','103141','26646','103178','100567','75159','103744','103244','78557','103330','102602'<500 numbers....>,);

    if ($value != $rcnumber) {
        $element->addError('Invalid RC Number');
        $valid = false;
    }
    return $valid;
}
add_filter('iphorm_element_valid_iphorm_14_11', 'custom_validator', 10, 3);
```

The problem with this code is that no matter what value I enter in rcnumber field I keep getting 'Invalid RC Number' error even though the number IS among 500 listed in the rcnubmer array. What am I doing wrong?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure of what you want to get here, but it looks like you want to check if a value exists in an array.

Try this:

```
if (!in_array($value, $rcnumber))
```

Instead of:

```
if ($value != $rcnumber)
```

in_array function will look for a value in an array, your current code checks if $value is different that the given array.